# How to request information from CouchDB using the URL?

Tags: javascript, html, url, couchdb

We have all seen the php+mysql thing - you write http://example.com/thenewarticle and get an html page with the new article, all the comments and weather information.

Can the same be done with javascript+CouchDB? Like http://example.com/doc5 would return a html page with some data from doc5 document in http://example.com/couch/ database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couch Db uses [couch apps](http://couchapp.org/page/index) that can be used to serve html pages.However it is not a replacement for traditional application servers built using php or any other language.Couch apps are good for simple html pages but for complex operations you will find it lacking.